# Use SystemVerilog parameters to decide which module to instantiate

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there a way to select the module I want to instantiate using the parameter values passed into the parent module? Example below

```
module parent ();

 parameter WORD = 1; 

 child_`WORD child (); // obviously does not work

endmodule
```

If `WORD == 1`, I would like to instantiate the child_1 module, for `WORD == 2`, the child_2 module and so on. Surely, someone has had a need to do this before?

Comment: I don't think it's possible if WORD has to be a parameter. You can either make WORD a text macro, or assemble the string using non-preprocessor mechanisms. You might get better answers if you describe what the original problem is.

Comment: I'd 2nd the opinion that this is not possible, and also ask you to explain why you want to do this or what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to conditionally instantiate a module, you need to use a `generate` block.

```
generate
  if (WORD == 1) begin
    child_1 child();
  end
  if (WORD == 2) begin
    child_2 child();
  end
endgenerate
```

Below is a full working example. Note that it only accounts for the presence of child_1 and child_2. You cannot use the parameter as part of the module type name that you are instantiating. If you have N child modules and you don't want to explicitly enumerate them all in the generate block, you would probably need to create a helper macro.

BTW, this is valid Verilog code; it doesn't use any SystemVerilog features.

```
module child_1();
  initial begin
    $display("child_1 %m");
  end
endmodule

module child_2();
  initial begin
    $display("child_2 %m");
  end
endmodule

module parent();
  parameter WORD = 1;

  // Conditionally instantiate child_1 or child_2 depending 
  // depending on value of WORD parameter.
  generate
    if (WORD == 1) begin
      child_1 child();
    end
    if (WORD == 2) begin
      child_2 child();
    end
  endgenerate

endmodule

module top();
  parent #(.WORD(1)) p1();
  parent #(.WORD(2)) p2();
endmodule
```

Output from Incisive:

```
child_1 top.p1.genblk1.child
child_2 top.p2.genblk2.child
```